# Unset the variables of a view for sub-views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Event');
        $todays_events = $this->Event->get_todays_events();     

        $data = array(
            'todays_events' => $todays_events
        );
        $this->load->view('main/index', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

main/index view

```
<?php $this->load->view('partial/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('components/calendar/mon_to_wed'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('partial/footer'); ?>
```

components/calendar/mon_to_wed

(Has access to $todays_events, why is this?)

```
<div id="calendar_today">
    <h1>Whats Happening</h1>
    <?php foreach($todays_events as $event) : ?>
        <?php var_dump($event); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the CodeIgniter core files, while hacking the core may solve this issue, another method exists that help to prevent defining variables in inner-views.

In the first `view` file, do this instruction:

```
foreach ($_ci_vars as $key => $value) $_ci_vars[$key]=NULL;

$this->load->view('your-inner-view', $_ci_vars);
$this->load->view('your-second-inner-view', $_ci_vars);
$this->load->view('your-third-inner-view', $_ci_vars);
// and so on...
```

I'll update my post, if I find a better solution

**UPDATE:**

Finally! I found the real solution, it is better to make your own `Loader` class instead of using default one. do the instructions below:

- Copy `Loader.php` class from `/system/core/` to your `/application/core/`
- Find `$this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);` at line #805
- change/replace that line to `$this->_ci_cached_vars = $_ci_vars;`

CodeIgniter has a variable cashing, once you use `load->view()` method, the variables will be cached in an array, and the second using of `load->view()` caused to merge `cached` variables and `new` variables if exists and then cache the result as a new array (which contains the old variables).

So, stop using of `array_merge()` would be the solution ;)

Comment: My only comment on this would be to extend the loader class and only copy this method to your new class. Much less code to maintain if you have to upgrade versions of CI.

Answer (score 0):

The given answer might work for single views, when assembling a view out of multiple sub-views, any data for the overall view gets deleted by the above fix.

What works for me is to explicitly set those data items for the sub-view to `null` if they are not needed.

For instance the sub-view expects `$a`, `$b` and `$c`.

The first time we render the sub-view we pass `$data['a'=>'whatever', 'b'=>'whatever', 'c'=>'whatever']` and the view is rendered correctly.

The second time we pass `$data['a'=>'whatever']`, $b and $c get rendered in the sub-view with the data from the first call.
If instead we pass `$data['a'=>'whatever', 'b'=>null, 'c'=>null]`, **b** and **c** do not get rendered in the sub-view.

This is of course assuming you are checking whether the data is null before you use it in the sub-view.